# Is my device vulnerable to the SwiftKey update bug? (June 2015)

Tags: security, samsung, bugs, swiftkey

Quoth [The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/samsung-galaxy-hack-swiftkey-vulnerability-lets-hackers-easily-snoop-on-phones-10325574.html):

> There are usually protections in place that stop hackers from performing what is called a “man in the middle attack”, by encrypting communication with the server, as well as ones to stop any malicious code from getting too deep into the phone. But Samsung has given its version of the software special permissions, which means that hackers can get through the protections in Android that stop third-party apps from tampering with other bits of the device.
>   ...
>   Researchers have confirmed that the exploit works on versions of the Samsung Galaxy S6, the S6 and Galaxy S4 Mini. But it may also be active on other Samsung Galaxy phones, since the keyboard software.

- Does this vulnerability have a formal CVE reference?
- How can find out if my device is vulnerable?
- How can I tell if a fix has been successfully deployed?

Comment: [This](https://www.nowsecure.com/blog/2015/06/16/remote-code-execution-as-system-user-on-samsung-phones/) may be worth reading. It does provide a step by step guide/explanation (inc. proof of concept exploit) that may help you verify if you're vulnerable. I believe this issue has been assigned [CVE-2015-2865](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/155412)